# MIPS Special Case Floating Point

Tags: assembly, mips

I have an assignment about MIPS. I should write a subprogram, which receives one argument in $a0 and delivers one result in $v0.  If the input argument, interpreted as an IEEE 754 32-bit floating point number, is one of the special cases (+/- infinite, NaN, zero, denorm), then the return value is 1 , meaning “yes”.  Otherwise, the return value is 0 meaning “no”.  My routine must not use any floating point instructions; it can only use the integer instructions to look at the bit field.

My question is how can I define or store an 32-bit float point as integer without using only integer instructions? If I can handle this part, I can use shifting and masking to identify the argument. I am not asking the answer of my assignment. I just need clue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You receive it in $a0 so you already have that float as an integer, zero instructions required

Comment: So,  Should I declare 32 bit binary value  initially and put it's adress into $a0 register? But how can I declare it like (0000100000...which is 32 bits) as an integer? @harold

Comment: The assignment, the way you have described it, says it should take the value not its address. So the input is just an integer.  So that's also what you pass in, if you must, though you've only written that you must write the subprogram and not whatever calls it. Anyway I don't really get what the problem is

Comment: `li $a0,0x7f800001  # NaN`, `li $a0,0x7f800000  # +Inf`, `li $a0,0xff800000 # -Inf`

Comment: I have handled it. Thanks @Michael